# Splitting UK 240V AC power leads - separate fuses needed?

Tags: electrical

I have four power supplies on my desk for laptops/monitors, each rated as drawing 1.0A or 1.6A at 240V AC. They're currently in a small drawer with four 240V leads going in and four low-voltage leads coming out. The leads are plugged into an extension cord just below the drawer and all the excess cable is coiled up inside the drawer, and I want to avoid this.

I'd like to create a 1:4 splitter lead to save space: BS 1368 plug, ~50cm cable, connector box, 4x ~15cm leads with C5 or C13 connectors.

Should I fit individual 2.5A fuses for each outlet lead? Or can I pack it all neatly into a single £1 Chocbox?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just buy a 4-way extension? Few quid in Asda, or anywhere.
One 13A fuse for the whole lot. You could swap it for a 5 or 10A, but no-one ever does. 2.5A are rare [& usually slo-blow, which isn't what you need for this type of installation]. You can get 3's but 4 individually-fused sockets is just complete overkill for a few wall warts.

[image]

BTW, you can stack 4-ways, so long as the total load doesn't exceed 13A - & if it would get anywhere near that, so long as the cables between aren't coiled up together or buried in anything that would insulate.

Comment: That's pretty much the current setup. I have an 8-way extension lead on the desk currently in the aperture that used to contain a drawer. In the drawer above: power supplies x4 for laptops/monitor plus several metres of coiled power lead x4, tightly packed in. I want to slim this down so I can actually open the drawer without dismantling the desk.

Comment: You could save a little space by buying a C14 power bar, putting C13 plugs on all the devices and a 1363 plug on the power bar's cord.  Seems a little desperate though, and fabricating your own power bar seems even more so.   Perhaps moving all this out of the drawer and thinking of other available space is a better approach.   Under-desk cable trays?  Screw the power bar to the side/back/underside of the desk?  Strap the PSUs to the monitor arms?  Combinations of these to make good use of the space you have, rather than creating a frankencord to prolong the agony of your small drawer.

Comment: Thanks - the existence of those power bars answers the question. They don't have individual fuses (as far as I can tell from photos on Amazon) so I should be right with a chocbox and terminal blocks! Although… now you mention it… I might be able to mount the power supplies underneath the desk. I'll look into that, thanks.